# Why are the results of of str == str.intern() for these strings different?

Tags: java, string, string-interning

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = new StringBuilder("计算机").append("软件").toString();
    System.out.println(str1.intern() == str1);
    String str2 = new StringBuffer("ja").append("va").toString();
    System.out.println(str2.intern() == str2);
}
```

Results:

```
 true
 false
```

First one prints `true`, and the second prints `false`. Why are the results  different?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()

Comment: sorry! I don`t understand what`s your point?

Comment: Why not? There's no reason why either of them should return `true`, or why they should both return the same result.

Comment: @side Please use apostrophes instead of back ticks, unless you want to highlight code.

Answer (score 20):

The difference in behavior is unrelated to the differences between `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer`.

The javadoc of [`String#intern()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern--) states that it returns

> When the intern method is invoked, **if the pool already contains a
>   string equal to this `String` object as determined by the `equals(Object)`
>   method, then the string from the pool is returned**. Otherwise, this
>   `String` object is added to the pool and **a reference to this `String`
>   object is returned.**

The `String` created from

```
String str2 = new StringBuffer("ja").append("va").toString();
```

is a brand new `String` that does not belong to the pool.

For

```
str2.intern() == str2
```

to return `false`, the `intern()` call must have returned a different reference value, ie. **the `String` `"java"` was already in the pool**.

In the first comparison, the `String` "计算机软件" was not in the string pool **prior** to the call to `intern()`. `intern()` therefore returned the same reference as the one stored in `str2`. The reference equality `str2 == str2` therefore returns `true`.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the other example behaves differently though

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The quote _Otherwise, this String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String object is returned._ isn't good enough?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: the other string is interned as well, the only difference is the stringbuilder/stringbuffer and the different character set

Comment: @JeroenVannevel You misunderstand. Character sets are irrelevant. If an equal `String` is in the pool, `intern()` returns a reference to **that** `String`, otherwise it returns a reference to **this** `String`. In the first case, it returned a reference to **this** `String`, which is why `true == (this == this)`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Ahh so the implicit reason is that "java" is already in there in a brand-new project, even though we haven't added that string ourselves. That's the piece I was missing.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Yeah, something in the JVM (or through some other bootstrapped class) must be adding it. I wanted to propose that you can verify by simply doing `"java" == str2.intern()`, but that would skew the results as we're now, ourselves, adding it to the pool.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I wanted to verify it to be sure and indeed, a heap dump shows it's in there. http://i.imgur.com/Fv5pbFV.png

Answer (score 5):

Because your assignments don't re-read from the [intern pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) and Java `String`(s) are immutable. Consider

```
String str1 = new StringBuilder("计算机").append("软件").toString();
String str1a = new String(str1); // <-- refers to a different String 
str1 = str1.intern();
str1a = str1a.intern();
System.out.println(str1a == str1);
String str2 = new StringBuffer("ja").append("va").toString();
String str2a = new String(str2); // <-- refers to a different String 
str2 = str2.intern();
str2a = str2a.intern();
System.out.println(str2a == str2);
```

The output is (as you might expect)

```
true
true
```

Comment: so that means str1 and str1a have the same reference

Comment: @side Any time two Object(s) are equal with `==` they have the same reference.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of answer before mentioned about the pool and explained really clearly with the Oracle link docs.

I just would like to point out the way we can check when debugging code.

```
    String str1 = new StringBuilder("计算机").append("软件").toString();
    System.out.println(str1.intern() == str1);//the str1.intern() returns the same memory address the str1
    String str2 = new StringBuffer("ja").append("va").toString();
    System.out.println(str2.intern() == str2);//the str2.intern() does not return the same memory address the str2
```

You can use any IDE and debug to check the actual address that the str1 and str1.intern()/str2 and str2.intern().

Answer (score 0):

let me add something more interesting:

1. **the OpenJDk 8 is true,true;**
2. **Oracle JDK 6 is true,true;**

so I think the right answer is :

diffrent vendor's jvm or jvm versions may have diffrent implemention(the language specification don't force the how to)

In Oracle JDK 8（I guess u using）:
**String “java” already in pool(loaded by java.lang.Version#laucher_name) and String pool only stores the refrence,not the object.**

But **in OpenJDK the laucher_name is "openJDK"；In Oracle JDK 6 and below ,the string pool will copy the string object to itslef**.